# Building Kiwi Browser for older Android versions

Tags: android, build

A good fork of Chromium browser, called Kiwi, is available to Android via Google Play Store. However, since August 2021 only for Android 5.0+. Previously it was 4.1+.

Url to Kiwi Github repo: https://github.com/kiwibrowser/android

Can someone please help me, how to build the Kiwi Browser for Android 4.1+ now? As far as I know, the newest version of Kiwi Browser also don't use any Android API 21 (5.0) features. I don't find any information, why suddenly minimum Android version 4.1+ was replaced by 5.0+. And also not find any readme, how to build your own Kiwi Browser for older Android.

Answer (score 0):

## Download the source code of *older* release

You can download source code of older release [here(scroll)](https://github.com/kiwibrowser/src/releases) one such example [here](https://github.com/kiwibrowser/src/releases/tag/241112321)

### Download the `source code.zip`

#### develop

##### enjoy

Comment: Okay, and then how to build? And where to select/"degradate" the Android SDK (minimum) version?